# Set android:windowIsFloating programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, android-resources

How can I set following activity style attribute programmatically

```
          <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
```

Comment: Maybe, do you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to create a new style with only the `windowIsFloating` attribute set. Then, overwrite the `getTheme` method on your targeted activity in order to set that style. (Assuming `AppTheme.NoActionBar` is you current style).

*styles.xml*

```
<style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>
```

*TargetActivity.java*

```
@Override
public Resources.Theme getTheme() {
    Resources.Theme theme = super.getTheme()
    theme.applyStyle(R.style. MyCustomStyle, true)
    return theme
}
```